# Find a string in a zipped file without unzipping the file

Tags: c#, string, zip, archive

Is there a way to search for a string within a file(s) within a zipped folder WITHOUT unzipping the files?

My situation is I have over 1 million files zipped by months of the year.
For example 2008_01, 2008_02, etc.
I need to extract/unzip only the files with specific serial numbers within the files.

The only thing I can find is unzipping the data to a temporary location to perform that search, but it takes me 45-60 minutes just to unzip the data manually. So I assume the code would take just as long to perform that task, plus I don't have that much available space.

Please Help.

Comment: So you traded space for time-to-search. Regardless of the compression algorithm and if serial number will survive, i think you should make (and keep maintained) an index file (or database) of all serial numbers, that allows you to look up the file needed. why search all files when you can do an indexed search

Comment: I believe you should be able to unzip the files as a stream and search the stream - depending on file size, you could keep the whole file in memory and then save it, or just re-extract that matches.

Comment: Do you have 1 million zip files that contain 1 file each?  Or, a single Zip file that contains a million files?  Or N zip files that contain M files each (where NxM == 1 million)?  The solutions would be somewhat different depending on your situation.

Comment: each zipped folder contains over 100k+ files. So to be honest there are more than 1 million files to query through.

Comment: Do you know which files you need to search (i.e. their full path) beforehand? Because you can extract the file contents for a specific file from a .zip without unzipping the whole archive.

Comment: Are the files text files with lines? Are the serial numbers always contained completely on a single line?

Comment: I don't understand why this is yet another SO question getting slammed by voting. I have the same question. What is the objection to asking if there is a tool you can use to search multiple .zip files without unizipping them first? Sounds totally reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do this. The zip format maintains an uncompressed manifest that shows file names and directory structure, but the contents of the files themselves are compressed, and therefore any string inside a file won't match your search until the file is decompressed.

This same limitation exists with just about any general-purpose file compression format (7zip, gzip, rar, etc.). You're essentially reclaiming disk space at the expense of CPU cycles.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to hear, but at least I know my options. I will just try different methods of moving the files to a temp location to query the files for the serial numbers and deleting the ones that don't match.

Comment: As @netmage pointed out above, you don't necessarily have to unzip everything to the file system (depending on your situation)

Comment: Yeah that is one of the methods I will consider. I'll just make a class for each option an see which one is faster. Bottom line is it's going to take me a long time to finish this.

Comment: I believe with a deep understanding of the compression format it may be possible to scan the bitstream for the compressed match desired, but I'm not sure it would be more efficient than uncompressing.

Answer (score 0):

Using some extension methods, you can scan through the `Zip` files. I don't think you can gain anything by trying to scan a single zip in parallel, but you could probably scan multiple zip files in parallel.

```
public static class ZipArchiveEntryExt {
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetLines(this ZipArchiveEntry e) {
        using (var stream = e.Open()) {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream)) {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    yield return line;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class ZipArchiveExt {
    public static IEnumerable<string> FilesContain(this ZipArchive arch, string target) {
        foreach (var entry in arch.Entries.Where(e => !e.FullName.EndsWith("/")))
            if (entry.GetLines().Any(line => line.Contains(target)))
                yield return entry.FullName;
    }

    public static void ExtractFilesContaining(this ZipArchive arch, string target, string extractPath) {
        if (!extractPath.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal))
            extractPath += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;

        foreach (var entry in arch.Entries.Where(e => !e.FullName.EndsWith("/")))
            if (entry.GetLines().Any(line => line.Contains(target)))
                entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.Name));
    }
}
```

With these, you can search a zip file with:

```
var arch = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath);

var targetString = "Copyright";
var filesToExtract = arch.FilesContain(targetString);
```

You could also extract them to a particular path (assuming no filename conflicts) with:

```
var arch = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath);

var targetString = "Copyright";
arch.ExtractFilesContaining(targetString, @"C:\Temp");
```

You could modify `ExtractFilesContaining` to e.g. add the year-month to the file names to help avoid conflicts.